# I am stuck in a chat application using FCM and web-socket

Tags: android, laravel, websocket, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

Techs: Laravel + JS + Android + Ratchet + FCM Push NOtification + PWA

**1. The first method (API)**

user get all messages from get API and send the message in post API

Problem: the user has to refresh the page to check the new message

Solution: Web Socket

**2. The second method (API + WebSocket)**

The first time we get all history from API and send the message using the socket and save them using post API, now chat automatically get updated on message event of the Web Socket

Problem 1(Can be ignored): Web Socket is running on a secure server with wss and android client below version 4.4 are not connecting to wss.(We have to accept all SSL which is dangerous).

Problem 2(Important): PWA or on browser like chrome and firefox on android not connecting to web socket.

**3. Now FCM come to the rescue**

Solutions: Work on every platform

Problem: Third party, Not so real-time, does not work in countries like China, Pakistan, Iran etc...(where Google is banned). And I have to leave my idea of using web socket(This was our first attempt).

Comment: Please, be more specific about your question. No one here knows more about your problem than you.

Comment: I am asking which method should I use WebSocket or FCM.. or there is any other way.